# Count the number of times a button appears

Tags: jquery

I am trying to count the number of times that the `fadeToggle` button appears and include it in `<p>` paragraph element as text.

```
$(function () {
  var box = $("#box");
  var para = $("#p");
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    function toggleBox(i) {
      box.fadeToggle(500, function () {
        count++;
        para.text() = count(i);
      });
    }

    toggleBox(i);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you put a console.log (count) in there and make this a runnable stack snippet?

Comment: where console.log(count) ?

Comment: One line above or below count++  You should learn to use console.log sooner or later, it's an invaluable tool.  You really shouldn't have this fadeToggle function inside your for loop.  It looks messy and it is hard to read and build upon later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Its not a good thing to add a function inside a for loop like you did.. it will be better to put your fade animation inside a function then call the function inside of it after the fadeIn complete it will create the loop till reach the `max_count`
- Also in jquery use `para.text(count)` instead of `para.text() = count(i);`

With `fadeToggle` the action is happen after element show and after hide

```js
$(function () {
  var box = $("#box");
  var para = $("#p");
  var count = 1;
  var max_count = 10;
  toggleBox(box , para , count , max_count);
});

function toggleBox(box_selector , para_selector , count , max_count) {
  $(box_selector).fadeToggle(500, function () {
    $(para_selector).text(count);
    if(count < max_count){
      toggleBox(box_selector , para_selector , count + 1 , max_count);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#box{
  background : red;
  width : 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<p id="p"></p>
```

With `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` the action will happen after element hide show together

```js
$(function () {
  var box = $("#box");
  var para = $("#p");
  var count = 1;
  var max_count = 10;
  toggleBox(box , para , count , max_count);
});

function toggleBox(box_selector , para_selector , count , max_count) {
  $(box_selector).fadeOut(500, function () {
    $(box_selector).fadeIn(500 , function(){
      $(para_selector).text(count);
      if(count < max_count){
        toggleBox(box_selector , para_selector , count + 1 , max_count);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#box{
  background : red;
  width : 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<p id="p"></p>
```